# Why am I getting an error calling a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

Why is this returning an error when I try to call this function recursively in python3?

```
class Solution:
    def climbStairs(self, n: int) -> int:
        if n == 2:
            return 2 
        if n == 3:
            return 3
        else:
            return climbStairs(self, n - 1) + climbStairs(self, n - 2)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How do you try to call it? What error do you get? Please read [ask] and [mre], and show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour].

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what the error is?

Comment: @John Isn't it obvious? `NameError: name 'climbStairs' is not defined`. That said, OP *should* provide it.

Comment: @wjandrea It could be that, or it could be the wrong number of arguments, or it could be something about the class instantiation (which was not shown), or or or ...

Comment: @John Ah yeah, true, but this looks like a LeetCode challenge based on the `class Solution`, and IIRC, it takes care of that stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

is this a method (defined inside a class)?
If so:

```
class Your Class:
   def climbStairs(self, n: int) -> int:
       if n == 2:
           return 2 
       if n == 3:
           return 3
       else:
           return self.climbStairs(n - 1) + self.climbStairs(n - 2)
```

if it is not a method, it is a function

```
def climbStairs(n: int) -> int:
    if n == 2:
        return 2 
    if n == 3:
        return 3
    else:
        return climbStairs(n - 1) + climbStairs(n - 2)
```

Comment: It is a method. The formatting was messed up so it was unclear, but I fixed it.

Comment: `self.climbStairs(...)` is the right way to call an instance method